# Automapper issue after updating dotnet from 2.1 to 3.1

Tags: .net, automapper

I am updating dontnet from 2.1 to 3.1 and I'm having an issue with AutoMapper that worked on 2.1. The error is pretty vague and I'm new to dotnet and c#.

```
Error mapping types.
Mapping types:
Individual -> UpdateIndividual
Common.Individual -> Models.UpdateIndividual
Type Map configuration:
Individual -> UpdateIndividual
Common.Individual -> Models.UpdateIndividual
Destination Member: Sex"
```

Here is the map:

```
UpdateIndividual individualModel = mapper.Map<UpdateIndividual>(individual);
```

Here is the custom mapper (in startup.cs):

```
cfg.CreateMap<Common.Individual, Models.UpdateIndividual>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Sex, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (IndividualSex)Enum.Parse(typeof(IndividualSex), src.Sex)));
```

Here is the destination class:

```
namespace Models
{
 public class UpdateIndividual
 {
    public int IndividualID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public IndividualSex Sex { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Here is the IndividualSex class:

```
namespace Models
{
 public enum IndividualSex
 {
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
 }
}
```

Here is the source (Individual class):

```
namespace Common
{
 public class Individual
 {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
 }
}
```

I'm really not sure why it has any issue mapping. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can remove the `MapFrom`, this mapping is built in. But of course it depends on the value of that string.

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm getting errors trying to remove that. Also, I just started dotnet and c# so I might not be asking the right questions.

Comment: What's the value in `Individual.Sex`, the source of your mapping? It seems likely it's not a valid value for the enum.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I didn't even think to look at the request. I ported the json from swagger to postman and didn't give it a second thought. Thanks so much, you are correct the value wasn't even close to correct.